# What is the benefit of Redundant 'async' call may be reduced to 'kotlinx.coroutines.withContext'?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following piece of code:

```
suspend fun add(article: Article): Long {
  return CoroutineScope(IO).async {
    articleDao.add(article)
  }.await()
}
```

I want to wait for a result so use async. But Android Studio prompts me to optimize the code as follows:

```
suspend fun add(article: Article): Long {
    return withContext(CoroutineScope(IO).coroutineContext) {
      articleDao.add(article)
    }
  }
```

I just started learning kotlin coroutines, I know that `withContext` is used to switch threads.

But in this example, `withContext` also seems to be guaranteed to wait for a return value? Can you tell me more about this?

Comment: Some of these pages might be helpful: https://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin+withcontext+vs+async (and here's a [stack-overflow-only result list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+kotlin+withcontext+vs+async)).

Comment: `async {}.await()` most of the time is an anti-pattern. This is like saying: "I would like to execute this in the background. Ohh, actually no, I need to wait on it, so it is in the foreground". Most of the time this is exactly the same as not using async/await at all and executing the inner code directly. In your case, as you switched a dispatcher, IDE suggested to add `withContext()` which does exactly this - switches the dispatcher. Also, if `articleDao.add()` is/would be a suspend function, you don't need even this `withContext()` - just call the function directly and that's all.

Comment: The above comment explains it perfectly. There's also another problem with your code. You should not be creating a new `CoroutineScope()` in this function to pull a CoroutineContext from it. Just use IO directly. `withContext(IO) { //...` And finally, if your Dao function is defined as `suspend`, you don't need to switch contexts at all. A suspend function should already be running any blocking code it contains on an appropriate thread while it suspends. Room is designed correctly--its suspend functions don't block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 issues in your original snippet:

```kotlin
suspend fun add(article: Article): Long {
  return CoroutineScope(IO).async {
    articleDao.add(article)
  }.await()
}
```

You should never create a `CoroutineScope` like this locally in a function, this breaks the contract of [Structured Concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency).

Or in other words, you `Deferred<A>` created by `async` is prone to leaking since it's not coupled to your outer `suspend` scope, or any parent lifecycle.

This can be fixed by using the [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder) Scope builder.

```kotlin
suspend fun add(article: Article): Long {
  return coroutineScope {
    async {
      articleDao.add(article)
    }.await()
  }
}
```

The second issue, which you asked in your question is "the benefit of withContext".

The benefit of `withContext` is that it's much more optimised than `async`, it can detect if the coroutine is already inside of the desired `Dispatcher` and can then avoid scheduling. It also has a more optimised runtime, and doesn't require a `CoroutineScope` and thus doesn't require the `coroutineScope` builder.

```kotlin
suspend fun add(article: Article): Long {
  return withContext(IO) {
    articleDao.add(article)
  }
}
```

To summarise, `withContext` allows you to **efficiently** run a `suspend fun` on a desired `Dispatcher` or `CoroutineContext` avoiding unnecessary scheduling. Whilst `async` creates a `Deferred`, similar to a Java `Future`, that runs a `suspend fun` in **new** Coroutine.